# Crystal Sub-report returning incorrect data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a primary crystal report and attached a subreport by following the steps below;

1. I Created the report I want printed first as the primary report.
2. I then created the sub-report.
3. Both of these reports work fine in isolation.
4. I placed the subreport into the Report Footer so that it will print immediately after the primary report.

The primary report is a list of income and expenditure. The sub-report analyses the profit by cost centre. Both reports should show the same bottomline but analysed differently. (for example: Sales £100 less (list of) expenses totaling £50 = profit £50 in the primary report; £20 profit product A £20 profit product B and £10 profit product C in the sub report).

However, the subreport returns only three lines; total sales total expenses and profit and the narrative of the three lines is incorrect.

Comment: what is the issue here? number of rows returned wrong or calculation is wrong?

Comment: The sub report is showing the wrong lines

Answer (score 0):

I think your subreport should go in a line before the primary line. I.e insert a line below your primary line, move the primary line into that, and put the subreport in the line where you just moved from.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for that. I've tried moving the sub report to several different areas within the template but its not working. The data still reports the same just in a different layout. I'm thinking the parameters of both reports are conflicting in some way but now sure how. If I load the sub report into the report footer this is suppose to display the report without this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you should look at your extraction criteria to make sure they are the same in both the primary line and the footer. I have found the following usually explain items missed in the selection.

1. The joins in the database dialogue - left or right joins
2. The selection criteria in the select expert
3. The group criteria - one of your records does not have a value in a `group by` field.